# Why does my flexbox expand despite overflow:hidden/auto?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain this behavior? I've created two stacked flexbox children to be a simple outline for a full-screen web app. However, adding content inside of my top element seems to expand it, eventually pushing the bottom one off of the screen.

```js
var buttonEl = document.getElementById('addButton');

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var newEl,
        ulEl;
    
    // Create a list item element
    newEl = document.createElement('li');
    newEl.innerHTML = "Test List Item";
    
    // Add the list item element to the list
    ulEl = document.getElementById('list');
    ulEl.appendChild(newEl);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}
#top {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#bottom {
    flex-basis: 1em;
}
li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
    <button id="addButton">add list item</button>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    Bottom
</div>
```

Comment: Expand which way - vertically? If you mean vertically, then the issue is simple: If you don't define a *height* on the element, then it's going to automatically stretch (expand) vertically to contain the contents, regardless of how you set overflow.

Comment: @cale_b Haha, of course it would be that simple. Now, what would be an appropriate height to give something that is meant to size dynamically? Oh, CSS...

Comment: @cale_b If you have time to make up an answer, I'd love to give you the points for it. Also, that wasn't a rhetorical question, is any height appropriate if it's going to just be overridden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/1ejgybmv/.

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: lightblue;
}
#top {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom {
    flex: 0 0 1em;
}

li {
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

very easy. You're defining all elements with `overflow:hidden` at the top

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you overwrite the property for `#top` div with this:

```
#top {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Effectively "killing" that property you defined at first. Simply get rid of that `overflow-y` or define `overflow-y:hidden` and it will work. Remember that order of definitions in CSS is very important, so everything you add AFTER one definition will be overwritten by the new definition

Comment: of course it does. See http://jsfiddle.net/vunn9e0b/ , I forked your fiddle and added rows at will and never had a scroll

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not trying to get rid of a scroll bar. I'm trying to prevent the bottom flexbox from pushing off the screen. Add items until they fill past the bottom and notice the bottom box pushing further down with each additional element.

Comment: hmmmm, then not sure waht you're asking, because if it is what I think now, it's totally different to your approach and overflow has nothing to do with this. Do you mean having a FIXED header and footer and then have the inner content scroll as it's being added? Because it so, it's as easy as to set your header and footer with position:fixed (plus some styling) and that's it, you don't need anything else at all, but this is so different to your explanation and your code and approach I'm not sure if this is what you mean

Comment: I wanted two elements ("top" and "bottom") that, together, take up the full screen/browser viewing area. The bottom has a fixed height and the top should fill in the leftover space above it. Lastly, I wanted to do this using flexboxes. The code I provided worked for this but has one problem: the top element expands.